# how to set-up a struct member to a member func in Swift

Tags: swift, struct, func

in this struct

```
struct {
    let type : SaveType
    var saveFunc : (value:AnyObject) 

    init(model:Model) {
        type = model.type
        // how to set saveFunc based on value of type
    }

    func save1(value:AnyObject) {...}
    func save2(value:AnyObject) {...}
}
```

The value of `type` once set does not change.
How can I set the member variable `saveFunc` based upon the value of `type` ?

I want callers to call saveFunc(value) rather than checking the `type` variable and calling the appropriate version of save.

I don't want the switch to be called *everytime* saveFunc is called - all the information required is available at init() time - so I want to set-up this behaviour at init time.

Happy to receive a different approach as an answer.

Comment: why don't you just make `save1` and `save2` private and make `saveFunc` a normal method that will call either `save1` or `save2`?

Comment: @Sulthan good question I will edit my question for clarity. The reason is because I don't want the switch to be called *everytime* saveFunc is called

Comment: @carl It's quite likely that omitting the switch is a false optimization and any closure based solution is really going to be hiding/obscuring the desired functionality.

Comment: @DavidBerry I'm not looking for a switchless soln. Just a soln where the switch is executed only once per instance.

Comment: Yeah, I get that.  But the overhead of the switch statement is minimal and it's much clearer what the function is doing if the switch is right there than have a closure variable that is magically set that the caller is expected to know they have to call.  Really it sounds like a subclass/factory question to me, but obviously we don't have all the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use closures to do what you want:

```
struct Foo {
    enum FooType {
        case A
        case B
    }

    var type : FooType
    var save : ((AnyObject)->())?

    private func saveA(arg:AnyObject) {
        print("saveA(\(arg))")
    }

    private func saveB(arg:AnyObject) {
        print("saveB(\(arg))")
    }

    init(type:FooType) {
        self.type = type
        switch type {
        case .A:
            save = saveA
        case .B:
            save = saveB
        }
    }
}

Foo(type: .A).save?(1)
Foo(type: .B).save?(2)
```

Note that you probably also want a didSet on type if it can be set after the object is created.

It's also worth noting, that this is probably not the right solution to your problem.  It really seems like something that should be handled by a combination of subclassing and factory models instead of being handled by a type/switch solution.

Comment: well... this is the best answer so far. thanks, and a switch at least gives clarity

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do that, for example:

```
struct {
    let type : SaveType

    init(model:Model) {
        type = model.type
    }

    private func save1(value:AnyObject) {...}
    private func save2(value:AnyObject) {...}

    // let's just decide internally what to call
    func save(value:AnyObject) {
       switch (type) {
          case .Type1:
             save1(value)
          case .Type2:
             save2(value)
       }
    }
}
```

However, you can make the same decision in `init` and assign `save1` or `save2` to `saveFunc`. There are also other solutions but I think they are all more complicated.

Comment: I wanted to avoid the switch being called each time. The code path is known when the struct is initialised so I want to define which func is called when the init is called.

Comment: One can't reference self from init(). i.e. I can't reference save1() or save2() in the init.

Comment: @Carl You can assign a closure that will call `self`, e.g. `{ self.save1($0) }`. You could also make `saveFunc` a lazy computed property which is basically the same.